# reads txt from file, cut them into words, and display

Tags: c

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996) 
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static WORDS heap[10000];
int heapSize;

void InitHeap()
{
    heapSize = 0;
    heap[0].words = NULL;
    heap[0].count = -1;
}

void InsertHeap(char* string)
{
    heapSize++;
    strcpy(heap[heapSize].words, string); 

    int now = heapSize;
    while (heap[now / 2].words > string)
    {
        heap[now] = heap[now / 2];
        now /= 2;
    }
    strcpy(heap[now].words, string);
}

int DeleteHeap()
{
    char* minElement, lastElement;
    int child, now;

    strcpy(minElement, heap[1].words);
    strcpy(lastElement, heap[heapSize--].words);

    for (now = 1; now * 2 <= heapSize; now = child)
    {
        child = now * 2;
        if (child != heapSize && heap[child + 1].words < heap[child].words)
        {
            child++;
        }
        if (lastElement > heap[child].words)
        {
            strcpy(heap[now].words, heap[child].words);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy(heap[now].words, lastElement);

    return now;
}

typedef struct _WORDS {
    char    words[64];
    int     count;
}WORDS;


char* MakeToken(void)
{
    int i, j;  
    static char delim[256];
    memset(delim, 0x0, 256);

    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(i)) delim[j++] = i;
    }
    return delim;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0, cur = 0;
    FILE    *pFile;
    char    readLine[1024], *ptr;
    char *token = MakeToken();

    InitHeap();

    pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\dataset.txt", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("File open failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (fgets(readLine, 1024, pFile) != NULL) {
        ptr = strtok(readLine, token);
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            InsertHeap(ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, token);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
    {
        cur = DeleteHeap();
        printf("%s %d\n", heap[cur].words, heap[cur].count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message : Run-Time error #3
I want to make program that reads txt from file, cut them into words, and display on console. I make it, but it doesnt work. how to fix it?
I think static WORDS heap<- this part
or 
delete part is error. 
or its path is failure.

Comment: @Michael `typedef struct _WORDS {
    char    words[64];
    int     count;
}WORDS;`

Comment: `strcpy(minElement, heap[1].words);
    strcpy(lastElement, heap[heapSize--].words);` are wrong. They does not have  reserved memory.

Comment: `heap[0].words = NULL;` You are trying to set the address of `heap[0].words` to `NULL`.

Comment: `heap[now / 2].words > string` is wrong.  Meaningless comparison.

Comment: I erase it but still it doesn't work

Comment: don't i have to compare the new word with original word to put into heap?

Comment: @JohnNash Isn't your compiler emitting several warnings? Pay heed to them. Do not ignore them. If you do not get any warnings, enable them using `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @JohnNash Are you thinking of `strcmp`?

Comment: no i erase (heap[0].words to NULL)<- this part

Answer (score 0):

I see following errors in your code:

```
heap[0].words = NULL;
```

words is an array, not a dynamyc allocated pointer, so you cannot assign to NULL (you get a compiler error! Seems to me that the WORDS.word variable declaration is uncorrect).

```
strcpy(minElement, heap[1].words);
strcpy(lastElement, heap[heapSize--].words);
```

minElement and lastElement are not initialized and not allocated, so the strcpy function will fail.

Here is a way to correct the code, I changed the minimum possible. The following collect the words, count the number of occurences and print the result in alphabetical order:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct _WORDS { 
    char words[64]; 
    int count;
} WORDS;


static WORDS heap[10000];

int heapSize;

void InitHeap()
{
    heapSize = 0;
}

void InsertHeap(char* string)
{
    int num = 0;

    // Search string in heap array. if found, increase count.
    for(num = 0; num < heapSize; ++num)
    {
        if(strcmp(string, heap[num].words) == 0)
        {
            heap[num].count++;
            return;
        }
    }

    // If not found, add it to the array.
    strcpy(heap[heapSize].words, string); 
    heap[heapSize].count = 1;
    heapSize++;
}

char* MakeToken(void)
{
    int i, j;  
    static char delim[256];
    memset(delim, 0x0, 256);

    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(i)) delim[j++] = i;
    }
    return delim;
}

int compare(const void* v1, const void* v2)
{
    return strcmp((const char*)v1, (const char*)v2);
}

int main() 
{
    int i = 0, cur = 0;
    FILE *pFile;
    char readLine[1024], *ptr;
    char *token = MakeToken();

    InitHeap();

    pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\dataset.txt", "r");
    if(pFile == NULL) 
    {
        printf("File open failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(readLine, 1024, pFile) != NULL) 
    {
        ptr = strtok(readLine, token);
        while (ptr != NULL) 
        {
            InsertHeap(ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, token);
        }
    }

    // Order alphabetically the heap array.
    qsort(heap, heapSize, sizeof(WORDS), compare);

    for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", heap[i].words, heap[i].count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I erase NULL part.
how to fix strcpy part?

Comment: I updated the answer, sorry but the purpose of your code is not completely clear. Maybe you should add some more info in your question

Comment: I want to cut the txt file into words, get them into heap(also count them that how many times they appear in txt), and print in dictionary order. So every time I cut word, then compare with its parents node.

Comment: OK I modified the code following your clarifications. Now it should do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed some errors in the code and it started to produce some results. Since I do not understand completely your task, I cannot progress further. The working code is as follows:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct _WORDS { char words[64]; int count; }WORDS;

static  WORDS app_heap[10000];
int heapSize;

void InitHeap()
{
    heapSize = 0;
    app_heap[0].words[0] = '\0';
    app_heap[0].count = -1;
}

void InsertHeap(char* string)
{
    heapSize++;
    strcpy(app_heap[heapSize].words, string);

    int now = heapSize;
    while (app_heap[now / 2].words > string)
    {
        app_heap[now] = app_heap[now / 2];
        now /= 2;
    }
    strcpy(app_heap[now].words, string);
}

int DeleteHeap()
{
    char minElement[64], lastElement[64];
    int child, now;

    if(heapSize <= 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong call\n");
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(minElement, app_heap[1].words);
    strcpy(lastElement, app_heap[heapSize--].words);

    for (now = 1; now * 2 <= heapSize; now = child)
    {
        child = now * 2;
        if (child != heapSize && app_heap[child + 1].words < app_heap[child].words)
        {
            child++;
        }
        if (lastElement > app_heap[child].words)
        {
            strcpy(app_heap[now].words, app_heap[child].words);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy(app_heap[now].words, lastElement);

    return now;
}

char* MakeToken(void)
{
    int i, j;
    static char delim[256];
    memset(delim, 0x0, 256);

    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(i)) delim[j++] = i;
    }
    return delim;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0, cur = 0;
    FILE    *pFile;
    char    readLine[1024], *ptr;
    char *token = MakeToken();

    InitHeap();

    pFile = fopen("dataset.txt", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("File open failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (fgets(readLine, 1024, pFile) != NULL) {
        ptr = strtok(readLine, token);
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            InsertHeap(ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, token);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
    {
        cur = DeleteHeap();
        printf("%s %d\n", app_heap[cur].words, app_heap[cur].count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```